# Question involving continuity of function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Problem:

Function $f$ is defined: $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\in \mathbb Q$ and $f(x)=x$ for irrational $x$. I have to check continuity of function.

My work:

Let $c\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$. 
Exists rational sequence $x_n$ that converges to $c$, since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$. But then, from the continuity of function, we have $c^2=c=f(c)$, which is in contradiction with condition that c is irrational.

Let $c\in \mathbb Q$. Rational $c$ we can write as limit of sequence $c+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ and we have (like in previous part) that $c^2$ is limit of sequence $f(c+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n})=c+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$, from where is $c^2=c$, which is not correct for $c\notin \{0,1\}$.

It seems that function is discontinuous in every point of $\mathbb R$. Is my work ok? Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function is continuous at $x=0$. No other points exist in which the function is continuous.

Comment: It seems like it is also continuous at $x=1$. Is it right?

Comment: @alans Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

It is continuous at only two rationals i.e. $x=0$ and $x=1$. As for $c\in$ {$0,1$}, $f'(c-\epsilon)=f(c)=f'(c+\epsilon)$, for small $\epsilon>0$

Comment: Can you clarify that last statement? It seems false.

Comment: My bad..  thanks jdods.